# How to check the validity(timestamp) in the License for an Android app?

Tags: android, datetime, licensing

I would like to know if there is any possible means of getting a secure time in Android System.

For example, if I install an application and the rule is like it will expire after 30 days. How can i ensure that it does so? I know that the user can change the Date and Time, but i would like to know if there are some other means to ensure the validity of the Date and time? Is there any option to get a secure time or secure clock tics for the android system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches:

1. At the time of install, or first-run, store the local datetime in a settings file or db.  Now perform the time check on subsequent start-ups (current datetime minus stored datetime), and expire after 30 days.  If the user attempts to set the current datetime to before datetime of install, then show a warning dialog and exit out.
2. Same as (1), but at time of install, or first-run, get the time from a network time server, such as NIST's.  You can show the user a dialog saying a network connection is required for first-run.  [Example network time code here.](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0589.html)